# Button text not staying changed when editing table

Tags: swift, uitableview, editing

I have a tableview controller with dynamic cells. One of the cells has a button to toggle editing the table, so that the user is less likely to delete something and has to actively enable editing.

When they press the button it is supposed to toggle editing the table and the text of the button. Editing the table works, but the text for the button just flashes then goes back to the original text.

```
@IBAction func deleteTouched(sender: UIButton) {
    editing = !editing

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FieldInfoCell

    cell.deleteButton.titleLabel?.text = editing ? "Done" : "Delete Estimates"
}
```

I first tried referencing the sender instead of the button in the cell

```
@IBAction func deleteTouched(sender: UIButton) {
    editing = !editing

    sender.titleLabel?.text = editing ? "Done" : "Delete Estimates"
}
```

Why does the text flash to `Done` and then back to `Delete Estimates` when I enable editing?

Comment: instead of Button.titleLabel?.text try Button.titleLabel?.setTitle(title:forState...

Comment: @Johnykutty That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting text button's title label use setTitle method like

```
button.setTitle("<#your title#>", forState: .Normal)
```

Because button needs title, titleColor, image, backgroundImage, attributedTitle etc for each state(`.Normal`,`.Selected`,`.Highlighted` etc). Each time button changes its state these properties get refreshed based on the state - even if you set titleLabel.text or imageView?.image. You can set font,layer properties for `titleLabel` and `imageView`